# Java Eclipse - where is the tool box like in Visual Studio

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best GUI designer for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse)

Just downloaded the latest version of Java eclipse from Eclipse.org, Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Helios Service Release 2. Where is the toolbox where all  the buttons, labels texbox, the components in other words?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally NetBeans had the better GUI layout tools in the free IDE's. It is/was called Matisse.

I heard rumors it was replaced in Netbeans7 by some GridBagLayout thingy, so you might want to drop bacl to 6.9 if that is the case. Maybe it is just additional and Matisse is still there.

If you want to stick with Eclipse, then the MyEclipse version also comes out of the box with a version of Matisse, but this costs you some  money for a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one. See this question for some info on GUI designer plugins: [Best GUI designer for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse)

Comment: The latest version of Eclipse includes a well-reputed GUI designer donated by Google: http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2011/06/eclipse-indigo-released-with-windowbuilder-gui-tool-and-egit-10.ars