# Create GUI using Eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swt, awt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best GUI designer for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse)

Is there any Eclipse Plugin tool(s) who can help to create Graphical User Interface for (swing, awt or swt), because I'm tired of writing everytime the code of Panels, Labels, ...

Thanks

Comment: @jfpoilpret: WindowBuilder Pro has refactoring friendly bi-directional code generation, so you can modify generated code without "crashing" your design view.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes. Use [WindowBuilder Pro](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) (provided by Google). It supports SWT and Swing as well with multiple layouts (Group layout, MiGLayout etc.) It's integrated out of the box with Eclipse Indigo, but you can install plugin on previous versions (3.4/3.5/3.6):

[image]

Comment: The link in the answer seems to be dead. Use http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

Answer (score 10):

There are lot of GUI designers even like Eclipse plugins, just few of them could use both, Swing and SWT..

[WindowBuilder Pro GUI Designer - eclipse marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/windowbuilder-pro-gui-designer)

[WindowBuilder Pro GUI Designer - Google code home page](http://code.google.com/intl/cs-CZ/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html)

and

[Jigloo SWT/Swing GUI Builder - eclipse market place](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jigloo-swtswing-gui-builder)

[Jigloo SWT/Swing GUI Builder - home page](http://www.cloudgarden.com/jigloo/)

The window builder is quite better tool..

But IMHO, GUIs created by those tools have really ugly and unmanageable code..

Comment: is WindowsBuilder works with swingx? If so, how?

Comment: Frankly i don't use GUI designers, I have MigLayout ;], but anyway, looks like it is possible [see official forum thread](http://forums.instantiations.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5120&p=16229) ..

Comment: plus 1 for pointing me to MigLayout as this is new for me. And it is good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is one. It is an eclipse-plugin called Visual Editor. You can download it [here](http://www.eclipse.org/archived/)

Comment: According to the website the last release is 2 years ago, and it doesn't support Eclipse 3.3.

Comment: Then I would reccomend GWT - Window Builder as mentioned above...

Answer (score 0):

try http://code.google.com/p/swinghtmltemplate/

this will allow you to create gui with html-like syntax