# SWT widget creator?

Tags: eclipse, swt

My need is to design a wizard page where in I have to add SWT Labels, Text, Button etc. So rather than doing it pro-grammatically I want some plug-in which allows creating widgets by dragging and dropping like we do in C#, .Net. Is there any plug-in freely available for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check [Create GUI using Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533243/create-gui-using-eclipse-java) question, where you can find more alternatives. Windows Builder Pro is IMHO great tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WindowBuilder Pro, as released by Google has support for SWT widgets.