# Eclipse Standard or Eclipse IDE for Java Developers?

Tags: java, eclipse

What type of developer are each of these IDEs aimed at?  Is one IDE a superset/subset of the other?  What can I do using one and not the other?

I'm looking to do mostly desktop based (Windows) work for now so I believe I am correct in ignoring the Java EE [download](http://eclipse.org/downloads/) and focusing on these two.

The  [comparison of features page](http://eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=kepler) isn't helpful as I'm still new to Eclipse and Java. For example "Code Recommenders Developer Tools" means nothing to me yet.

Eclipse standard has been downloaded 1.7 million times and is 246MB (as at 7-Sep-13).  While Eclipse IDE for Java developers has been downloaded 430,000 times and is 151MB.

So I'm guessing Eclipse Standard is the way to go, but why do they offer the second option?

Comment: I have a same question. @mliebelt's answer comes close to explaining - but I'm still hoping for a better answer. http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php gives somewhat of an answer.

Answer (score 11):

All the other answers are more or less true, but miss the point (in my opinion), The [download page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) states it clearly:

> Eclipse Standard ...
>   The Eclipse Platform, and all the tools needed to develop and debug it

versus

> Eclipse IDE for Java Developers ...
>   The essential tools for any Java developer, including a Java IDE, a CVS client, Git client, XML Editor, Mylyn, Maven integration...

So if your focus is to develop for Eclipse  itself, the [Eclipse Standard](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-43/keplerr) includes all what you need (including the sources of all features and plugins).

If your focus is Java development (not Eclipse plugins), you should start with the [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/keplerr).

If your focus is Java EE development, it is simpler to start with [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplerr) and so forth ...

Answer (score 2):

The comparison page could certainly use some links, nevertheless a quick web search will tell you all about those plugin.

For your needs, **you might look into the "for Java Developers" package, as it contains [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/), which let's you define GUIs visually in several frameworks**.

([Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/) is also nice, but I've personally found it a bit hit-or-miss)

However, **you're fine installing any of the packages either way, since you can always install the plugins you need later on**. My recommendation is to simply read about those plugins and make an informed decision on what you should install.

Comment: I thought perhaps the IDE itself might be differently configured, ie tool windows, window layout, debugging tools etc.  I'm coming from the Visual Studio world where they have the basic Express editons and the full versions, express is for casual/new users and is configured that way.

Comment: @Ash : plugins in Eclipse are quite compartmentalized. Usually what you get is a different Perspective view geared towards a plugin (which you can further customize yourself), which you can switch between at will and customize further yourself. Or you just get new options for existing view, or new editors for specific files (like in the case of WindowBuilder). Regardless, I don't recall a 
"simple mode" analog in Eclipse. So, when in doubt, install the **minimum** set of plugins you know you need, **take some time to research additional ones**, and install them yourself. Eclipse is very DYI.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing GUI work then you might choose the Java Developers package as it comes with [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/).

Other similar questions are:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835305/what-are-my-options-for-developing-a-gui-in-java-in-eclipse
- [Best GUI designer for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse)
- [Create GUI using Eclipse (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533243/create-gui-using-eclipse-java)

Comment: OK, but I'm really asking why they provide the two separate downloads when it sounds like main difference is default plugins, and they can just be downloaded later if needed.

Comment: Yes, that's the difference in those terms. Eclipse itself is basically a plugin-environment, and the different bundles represent different sets of pre-installed plugins. You can pick-and-choose, mix-and-match, after installing as you come to realise what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the eclipse downloads are just the pre-installed plug-ins.

I'd go with standard and install the plug-ims i want, but take what fits you.

Comment: I read that text in the file download tooltips.  Doens't help me much.