# Java IDE for desktop developement

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans

I have to create a desktop application in java. I have experience in working with eclipse IDE for web development. Now for Desktop development whether i have to stick with eclipse or Netbeans.

Then, they are telling Eclipse RCP and Netbeans RCP, i heard only swing, Which framework can I use for desktop development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Window Builder](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html) from google is the best plugin I have ever seen for ui design.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, Eclipse is a perfectly cromulent IDE for desktop applications.

Is there any feature in particular you think you'll be missing which could be worth the inconvenience of re-training yourself with a different environment?

Answer (score 2):

Both Eclipse and Netbeans provide services to utilize and design Swing components. Swing is the general window toolkit for Java. Netbeans and Eclipse are IDEs. If you have experience with Eclipse, then use Eclipse as it will be easier for you.

If you need to design a user interface, which is what I think you are trying to get at, then something like [Visual Swing Designer](http://code.google.com/p/visualswing4eclipse/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use netbeans for swing because its just how I learned.

You can take this chance to learn something new or stay with what you are formiliar with. Only you can make that choice though.

Take into account things like deadlines etc.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I believe Swing would be the best option to go when you plan to develop desktop apps with java. When It come to IDE, as since eclipse is you are used to, better stick to that, for design swing interfaces you can use, some third party plugin of your choice. Number of designers available can be found here,

[Best GUI designer for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse)