# How to display in JFrame web browser view in order to display web page?

Tags: java, swing, browser

What is the best approach to put some web browser Panel on JFrame in JAVA application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use `JEditorPane` and its method `setPage(url)`.

Take a look at this: [How to use Editor Panes and Text Panes?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

Comment: What tool can I use to build GUI fast in Eclipse?

Comment: You need to have some GUI building plugin in your eclipse. That are number of plugins available out there, you can try them. I have not tried any of them so can't comment on that. This can help you decide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse

Comment: I red in tutorial that it will only extract text form html page, but I need to display some images as well./

Comment: @RCola It will also display images. http://www.google.co.in/search?aq=f&gcx=c&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=browser+in+swing

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any good web browser component for Swing. But JavaFX 2.0 has a web browser component, and you can embed JavaFx 2.0 components in a Swing application. See [Adding HTML Content to JavaFX Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm)