# desigining in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, netbeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best GUI designer for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse)

I have been working with netbeans and i am new to eclipse.I have opened the eclipse but how do i create automatic frames,buttons etc in eclipse.In netbeans i had to just select the `jframe` from new option and automatically it's related components would be there. But i am unable to do the same in eclipse. I click on new -> java project. Then create a main package containing the main class but how do i create the automatic frames in eclipse. I see no option there as seen in netbeans. `new->JFrame`

Comment: You need a GUI builder tool. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a plugin that will be a GUI builder tool. [*WindowsBuilder*](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html)  is a good tool to design in eclipse.

It is built as a plug-in to Eclipse and the various Eclipse-based IDEs. There are various others you can google around.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a plugin with eclipse for designing GUI. A comparison of different plugins is given here:

- [GUI Builder for Eclipse](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://wiki.computerwoche.de/doku.php/programmierung/gui-builder_fuer_eclipse&act=url)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for some Swing Designer plug-in. Take a look at http://www.formdev.com/ I've heard it's good, but I never used it myself.