# how to create a form in eclipse indigo?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin

I'm using Eclipse indigo. I'm a beginner in this platform. I'm trying to create a windows application using eclipse. How to create windows application and i can't find the tool kits that contain textbox, button and all. Please help me.

thanks.

Comment: Find for [Eclipse Swing Plugins](http://www.google.co.in/search?ix=seb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Eclipse+Swing+Plugins).

Comment: take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/29426/1007273

Comment: Google your way to *eclipse RCP* (rich client platform) and *SWT* (standard widgets toolkit). You'll find a lot of tutorials and books.

Answer (score 1):

eclipse doesn't come with a built-in window builder but try one from google for free. It's an addon. [Link](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html)

Comment: Just FYI: Eclipe 3.7 contains the window builder by default.

Comment: I know, I just included the info if he had an older version.