# Java for UI windows applications

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm .net developer and trying to study java.

I would like to know which kind of project ( on eclipse ) I can create Windows UI Applications like.

in Visual Studio this is very intuitive

any tips are welcome

Comment: *"in Visual Studio this is very intuitive..."*  Unfortunately in Java there's lots of choices - Swing, AWT, SWT, and even then you can have PLAFs (don't start me)..  It's very unintuitive (to have so many options).

Comment: I would point you towards questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533002/eclipse-gui-building), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942696/what-eclipse-gui-builder-plugin-do-you-suggest), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326109/i-am-looking-for-gui-editor-plug-in-for-eclipse) - they're just the first few results from a search for "Eclipse GUI builder."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew Thompson put it, there are a lot of choices in Java and so I would suggest you will probably want to start with the GUI introduction from the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/index.html) to get familiar yourself with the concept and terminology.

Then you can start to do the Java GUI tutorial (example swing) and I think this site is good on the [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Catalog0240__Swing.htm). If you want your application to look and feel like what you have in Windows application, then take a look at this example [code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/WindowslookandfeelinJava6.htm).

Last but not least, you will probably want to install this [plugin](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html) from google to your eclipse as it assist very much during Java GUI development.