# How to find a JFrame at swing library in Eclipse8.6?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I know that I have the swing library because I can add JFrames programmatically. However, I cannot add a JFrame in Eclipse with New > Other > Swing etc. as I do not have the Swing folder amongst my other Wizards.

Comment: Are you sure it is "Eclipse8.6" your working with?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such wizard in Eclipse. You need to extend Eclipse with Plugins to get similar features.

Formerly there was only one available for Eclipse, [Visual Editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/VE), but it has been deprecated and will be replaced by [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). In the meantime there are more GUI building plugins available: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse).

One plugin not mentioned there is [Swing GUI Designer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/swing-gui-designer), formerly named Matisse4MyEclipse. In the comments for this plugin you'll finde some references to other GUI builder/designer plugins.