# Altenative to Grid Bag Layout

Tags: java

Im not here for any code, just want to ask what is the best layout manager in JAVA to choose to create program.I used GridBagLayout but its not the best layout as it got border on each panel, i.e:between color and clear panel it got border. I want to create clear panel without border!

Comment: Components having borders has nothing to do with the layout.

Comment: For future reference, that type of question should be answered in other SO forums like [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it difficult directly answering your question because it is not fully clear to me. However, I can provide you a few references that might be able to help you.

The Java Tutorials offer a useful visual guide of layout managers:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#gridbag

Also, you might be interested in graphical user interface builder tools. This question has a few answeres pointing out a few links to such builders:

[Best GUI designer for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse)

Good luck