# Using Netbeans GUI settings in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, plugins

I did not find a working plugin after my tremendously long search for a plugin that works in eclipse. I want the Netbeans GUI-plugin, the one that allows you to modify and create different GUI:s without "coding" in eclipse. Is it possible to do? Where I can I find it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best GUI designer for eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like the eclipse windowbuilder? https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/